# Implementing Stack With (Key,Value)

Tags: java, algorithm, class, oop, data-structures

I am wondering if I can implement a stack with (Key, Value) like below:

```
    public static void main(String[] args) {
    PriorityQueueStack<Integer,V> s = new PriorityQueueStack<>();
    s.push(1,'A');
    s.push(2,'B');
    s.push(3,'C');
    s.push(4,'D');
```

My class implementation is like below:

```
  public class PriorityQueueStack<E> extends SortedPriorityQueue<Integer, E> implements 
  PriorityQueue<Integer, E>{
```

Is there a way to implement it with (Key, Value) as I have searched I couldn't find any resource of such an implementation.

The output should be like this:

```
 (1,'A'),(2,'B')..... and so on
```

Comment: Did you try using  java's Stack class with the type Pair class ?

Comment: You can use any type for a stack.  For this a `Map.Entry` comes to mind.  But for it to be a stack the elements still need to come out in `LIFO` order.

Comment: What is a "priority queue stack"? I don't see how you intend to marry those two concepts. Is this a data structure that should be a priority queue for the "keys" and a "stack" for the values?

Comment: These classes have the methods that I need to implement the stack @rootkonda

Comment: You are right but do you have a link documentation that explains that in detail? @WJS

Comment: priority queue stack is a name of my class @Joni

Comment: Yes, but how should it behave? Should it behave like a stack, or a priority queue?

Comment: I don't recommend you creating a spaghetti class.

Comment: It is a stack class using Priorityqueue. I am not clear yet on how it should behave.But the stack works as FIFO. @nylanderDev

Comment: @Tasneem `Map.Entry` is explained in the JDK API documentation.  And there are many articles on the web regarding LIFO and stacks.  I would check out Wiki.

Comment: Unfortunately, we can't help you with your implementation if you don't know what you're trying to implement.

Comment: *But the stack works as FIFO*  Then it's not a stack.

Comment: Ok, I am just asking to see if it is possible. I have tried to do it this way and tried to search for different ways but I could not find. The whole idea is I want to clear this concept of the stack implementation using priorityqueue. @ArvindKumarAvinash

Comment: It is not possible to create a Stack based on priorities, at least not while still calling it a stack.

Comment: Ok got the idea @nylanderDev. Thank you for clearing that

Answer (score 4, accepted):

It could be done by creating a **separate class for key-value pair** and **adding an object of that class in the Stack**.

```
class Pair{
    
    int key;
    char value;
    
    public Pair(int key,char value){
        this.key = key;
        this.value = value;
    }
    
}


public class Main {
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        Stack<Pair> stack = new Stack<>();
        stack.push(new Pair(1,'A'));
        stack.push(new Pair(2,'B'));
        stack.push(new Pair(3,'C'));
        stack.push(new Pair(4,'D'));
        // Pair p = stack.pop();
        // System.out.println(p.key+" "+p.value);
    }
}
```

Comment: Yes, It will work... and It's my pleasure that my answer helped you.

Comment: But there's no priority queue here

Comment: And as I said, you have `Map.Entry` which is a premade, class that can be used for this.

Comment: The idea is I needed (key and value) for my stack class. The rest is ok.@Joni

Comment: Sure I will take a look at Map.Entery too @WJS. Thank you

Comment: @Joni The main focus of the problem is to implement key-value pair stack. So I have followed the above approach.